# How to search by a field in mongoose with multiple keywords and sort results by the order the keywords are searched

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Product collection in mongoDB and I use mongoose. What am trying to achieve is, to search products by name

I have to search for the term "Los Angeles Lakers"

```
const results = await Products.find({
        $or: [
          { name: { $regex: "Los", $options: "i" } },
          { name: { $regex: "Angeles", $options: "i" } },
          { name: { $regex: "Lakers", $options: "i" } },
        ],
      });
```

This works fine. But I want to sort the results like, the search results of "Los" first, results of "Angeles" then, and the results of "Lakers" after that.

Also is there a way to accompish the above task similar to this

```
const results = await Products.find({
    $or: [
      { name: { $regex: $or: ["Los", "Angeles", "Lakers"], $options: "i" } }
    ],
  });
```

*This is my first stack overflow question so bare with me if this is long or not formatted right. Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Can you please add an input and output example? What happens if a prhase contains two or more regex values ("Los", "Angeles" or "Lakers"). Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2sqjqs-VKH3) and if it works ok.